# Include T4 generated files on the same folder of the template file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

I'm trying to add a saved file to the current project of my T4 template file.
The file is saved as expected by the `SaveOutput` method, but when I use the `IncludeInCurrentProject` method, that calls the `ProjectItems.AddFromFile` ([docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)), and then the file is added on the **root** of the project.

I'd like to include the file generated by the `SaveOutput` method on that exactly location on the project.

This is what I have right now:

[image]

Here is my .tt file:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".sql" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import Namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>

<#
    var MigrationName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("InputBox Label", "Description");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MigrationName))
        return "";

    var MigrationVersion = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    var MigrationFileName = MigrationVersion + "-" + MigrationName + ".sql";
    var MigrationFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile), "", MigrationFileName));
#>

My T4 template goes here

<#
SaveOutput(MigrationFilePath);
IncludeInCurrentProject(MigrationFilePath)
    .Open(Constants.vsViewKindPrimary)
    .Activate();
#>
<#+
    private void SaveOutput(string filename)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(filename, GenerationEnvironment.ToString());
        GenerationEnvironment.Clear();
    }

    private ProjectItem IncludeInCurrentProject(string filename)
    {
        return CurrentProject.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(filename);
    }

    private Project CurrentProject
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_currentProject == null) {
                var serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
                var dte = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;

                foreach(Project project in dte.Solution.Projects) 
                {
                    // workaround. dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(Host.TemplateFile).ContainingProject didn't work
                     string projectPath = project.FullName.Replace("\\" + project.FileName, string.Empty);
                     if(Host.TemplateFile.Contains(projectPath))
                     {
                        _currentProject = project;
                        break;
                     }
                }
            }
            return _currentProject;
        }
    }


    private Project _currentProject;
#>
```

How can I include my generated files on the same folder of the T4 template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CurrentProject.ProjectItems` always references the `ProjectItems` in the root.

I used the file path to navigate through the `ProjectItems` and call the `AddFromFile` on the correct one. You can check the `GetCurrentProjectItem` method, this behaviour is implemented there.

Now the template works fine:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".sql" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import Namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>

<#
    var migrationName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("InputBox Label", "Description");

    Regex alphaNumericRegex = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]");
    migrationName = alphaNumericRegex.Replace(migrationName, string.Empty);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(migrationName))
        return "";

    var migrationVersion = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    var migrationFileName = migrationVersion + "-InsertCourt" + migrationName + ".sql";
    var migrationFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile), migrationFileName));
#>

My T4 template goes here

<#
SaveOutput(migrationFilePath);
IncludeInCurrentProject(migrationFilePath)
    .Open(Constants.vsViewKindPrimary)
    .Activate();
#>
<#+
    private void SaveOutput(string filename)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(filename, GenerationEnvironment.ToString());
        GenerationEnvironment.Clear();
    }

    private ProjectItem IncludeInCurrentProject(string filename)
    {
        ProjectItem item = GetCurrentProjectItem().ProjectItems.AddFromFile(filename);
        item.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = "None";
        return item;
    }

    private ProjectItem GetCurrentProjectItem()
    {

        var serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
        var dte = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;

        string templateDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
        string foldersString = templateDirectory.Replace(Path.GetDirectoryName(GetCurrentProject().FullName), string.Empty);
        string[] foldersArray = foldersString.Split(new [] {"\\"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach(Project project in dte.Solution.Projects) 
        {
            ProjectItems currentProjectItems = null;

            foreach(string folder in foldersArray)
            {
                if(currentProjectItems == null) 
                {
                    currentProjectItems = project.ProjectItems;
                }

                foreach(ProjectItem projectItem in currentProjectItems) 
                {
                    if(projectItem.Name == folder) 
                    {
                        if(Array.IndexOf(foldersArray, folder) == foldersArray.Length - 1)
                        {
                            return projectItem;
                        }
                        currentProjectItems = projectItem.ProjectItems;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Project GetCurrentProject()
    {
        var serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
        var dte = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;

        foreach(Project project in dte.Solution.Projects) 
        {
            // workaround. dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(Host.TemplateFile).ContainingProject didn't work
            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(project.FullName);
            if(Host.TemplateFile.Contains(directory))
            {
                return project;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    private ProjectItem _currentProjectItem;
#>
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue, but when creating files from another project. I took your folder loop solution and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrea I'm glad that the solution helped you.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the IncludeInCurrentProject the input should be the path + filename.

Comment: Hello Pedro. The MigrationFilePath contains the full path (path + filename), this variable is sended to the IncludeInCurrentProject method.

Comment: Take a peek here: https://epsicode.com/2019/08/12/tutorial-generate-seperate-files-from-a-t4-template/ and adjust to your needs

Comment: Also, I write every output to different projects and folders here too: https://github.com/Epsilekt/TexTran/tree/master/src/TexTran.Transformer